# Is there a list of Cppcheck messages?

Tags: static-analysis, cppcheck

Our team previously used [Lint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pcl.htm) as a static code analyser, but it became too cluttered and had too much noise.

We are using C++03 with frequent use of [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29), and Lint didn't seem to like Boost (I hear this has become better in later versions). I started looking at other static code analysers and came across [Cppcheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cppcheck) and tried it out. I'm very impressed at what it warns about (I've seen about a dozen informationals and style problems).

What I'm interested in is: **Is there are a list of all Cppcheck messages that Cppcheck issues, similar to [how Lint](http://legacy.cleanscape.net/products/cpp/checks.html) and [PVS-Studio](http://www.viva64.com/en/d/0368/) both have a list of their messages?** The [official Cppcheck website](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) lists:

- Out of bounds checking
- Memory leaks checking
- Detect possible null pointer dereferences
- Check for uninitialized variables
- Check for invalid usage of STL
- Checking exception safety
- Warn if obsolete or unsafe functions are used
- Warn about unused or redundant code
- Detect various suspicious code indicating bugs
- …

But I'm more interested in something similar to Lint and PVS-Studio, and similar to how the results are displayed in Visual Studio:

```
ID | Category/Severity | Text
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A list of Cppcheck checks is available [at the project's wiki](http://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/wiki/ListOfChecks/), and as stated there, you can also get the list from the command-line by running:

```
$ cppcheck --doc
```

or

```
$ cppcheck --errorlist
```

The errorlist outputs an XML file with all three things you want. Here's a small example from it:

```
<error id="unnecessaryForwardDeclaration" severity="style" msg="The variable &apos;name&apos; forward declaration is unnecessary. Type variable is already declared earlier."/>
<error id="variableHidingEnum" severity="style" msg="variable &apos;name&apos; hides enumerator with same name"/>
<error id="unnecessaryQualification" severity="style" msg="The extra qualification &apos;type&apos; is unnecessary and is considered an error by many compilers."/>
```

To save the output to a file rather than the command window, use:

```
cppcheck --errorlist > errorlist.xml
```

Comment: I like that there's a list, I hate that it's in pure XML and nigh unreadable with all the &apos; in it.

Comment: @Tzalumen It's possible to reprocess with xmlstarlet: `cppcheck --errorlist | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//error" -v "@id" -o ": " -v "@msg" -n | xmlstarlet unesc`